# I was creating a ditto zig zag game i.e. available on Google play store by Ketchapp, Can anyone help me with the specific platform generation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

[image]
[image]

So, in the above images you can see my script generates platform though I want to limit the generation to only main camera's width i.e. the generated platform should not go beyond camera screen width. If you had played the available game you will know.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PathGenerator : MonoBehaviour

{
    private Vector3 spawnPos;
    [SerializeField] Vector3 lastPos;
    [SerializeField] float offset;
    [SerializeField] GameObject trackPrefab;

    private GameObject temp;

    [SerializeField] int amountToPool;
    List<GameObject> platformPool = new List<GameObject>();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        CreatePath(amountToPool);
        UsePath();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void CreatePath(int amt)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < amt; i++)
        {
            temp = Instantiate(trackPrefab);

            temp.transform.SetParent(GameObject.Find("Tracks").transform);

            platformPool.Add(temp);
        }
    }

    private void UsePath()
    {
        foreach (GameObject p in platformPool)
        {
            RandomPicker();

            p.transform.position = spawnPos;

            lastPos = p.transform.position;
        }
    }

    public void RespawnTrack(GameObject pathGameObject)
    {
        RandomPicker();

        pathGameObject.transform.position = spawnPos;

        lastPos = pathGameObject.transform.position;
    }

    private void RandomPicker()
    {
        var randomNumber = Random.Range(0, 2);
        if (randomNumber < 1)
        {
            spawnPos = new Vector3(lastPos.x - offset, 0, lastPos.z);
        }
        else
        {
            spawnPos = new Vector3(lastPos.x, 0, lastPos.z - offset);
        }

        lastPos = spawnPos;
    }
}
```

[image]

I want to move my cam exactly and also you see how the platforms are never off screen.

Comment: OK, sounds reasonable, whats actually stopping you from acheiving it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired effect you'll need to limit the spawn position when generating the path.

In your `RandomPicker` function, you're setting the next position to either be to the right or the left from the last position, here's where you can limit the position

```
    //.....
    float minX, maxX;
    float modelWidth = 4;

    private void Start()
    {
        //...rest of the code

        minX = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Vector2.zero).x + modelWidth;
        maxX = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Vector2.right * Screen.width).x - modelWidth;
    }


    private void RandomPicker()
    {
       //...rest of the code

       spawnPos.x = Mathf.Clamp(spawnPos.x, minX, maxX);
       lastPos = spawnPos;
 }
```

**Solution explanation**:
You can grab the screen info using the `Screen` class and its static members, such as `width`. This, however, will return info in "Screen space" coordinates, so we can use [`Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) to translate that info up.

Also, to fully achieve the desired effect, you'll want to line up the spawned path borders. Doing this on different `path` object sizes can be tricky, so be aware of the positioning and pivoting of the paths when creating/designing them

Some considerations when working with this kind of rule

- `Screen` => Actual game screen, so it will reflect both the camera configuration and the running game (such as resizable windows)
- Position zero in `Screen coordinates` refers to the bottom left corner, whereas the "max" position (using `Screen.height` and `Screen.width`) will return the top right corner

*Note: this code snippet will only works on ortographic cameras, but can be managed on perspective ones.*